q-Pochhammer expression
I am looking for a way to express the q-Pochhammer symbol (a; q)n which is explained on Wikipedia as follows:
q-Pochhammer symbol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) Wikipedia
What I am not looking for is a way to evaluate to q-Pochhammer symbol (a; q)n for given numerical values a, q, n as the function q_poch in q_analogues.py https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/combinat/q_analogues.py#L557 or the function qp in mpmath.py https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/qfunctions.html does.
My aim by expressing the q-Pochhammer symbol (a; q)n and using it symbolically is to simplify a complex expressions like f = q**(n*k) * q_pochhammer(q**(-n-1), q**(-1), k) * q_pochhammer(q**(-n+1), q, k) by using simplify(f) and fractionise it then by numerator / denumerator = fraction(f). in order to yield the numerator and denumerator
Overall it is about transforming a complex expression containing one or more q-Pochhammer symbols into a rational expression f = numerator/denumerator.
Any ideas?
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
#from mpmath import *

n, k, q = sp.symbols('n,k,q')


def fun_rational(fun, variables=[]):
    fun = fun.simplify()
    num, denum = fraction(fun)
    print(num)
    print(denum)
    print(type(num))
    print(type(denum))


fun_rational(binomial(n+1,k)/binomial(n,k))

fun_rational(factorial(n)/factorial(n - 3))

fun_rational(q**(n*k) * q_pochhammer(q**(-n-1), q**(-1), k) * q_pochhammer(q**(-n+1), q, k))


What about the code you have shown? Would it be an idea to use it?

Well, I had a closer look into the two functions factorial () https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/2197797741156d9cb73a8d1462f7985598e9b1a9/sympy/functions/combinatorial/factorials.py#L36-L279 and binomial() https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/2197797741156d9cb73a8d1462f7985598e9b1a9/sympy/functions/combinatorial/factorials.py#L828-L1133. I think, to make thinks work in the manner I want, I have in ananlog way to develop a similiar function in python for the Q-Pochhammer function. My guess: this ist not an easy and quick fix.
